# Prove a number is even using the Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Let *n* be an odd integer and let *f* be an [n]-permutation of length *n*, where [n] is the set of integers 1, 2, 3,...n

Show that the number

```
x = (1-f(1))*(2-f(2))*...*(n-f(n))
```

is even using the pigeonhole principle

In this case, I don't understand what this function *f* is. What is an [n]-permutation of length *n*? Take *f*(2) for example. Permutations of [2] would be 1,2 and 2,1. So the way the problem is worded, *f*(2) must equal 12 or 21. If that's correct, which one? Will this number *x* still be even regardless of which [n]-permutation *f*(n) is?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I guess you mean even. For odd it won’t work.

Comment: Yes, sure. =) ${}$

Comment: $f$, should be written $f_n(i)$ and is the $i$th element of some permutation of $(1, 2, \dots n)$.

Comment: I think the confusion also stems from the fact that the information of being an permutation of the set $[n]$ and having length $n$ is redundant. I don’t think the term _length_ is commonly used for a general permutation, but rather for cyclic ones.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the abuse of the term permutation in "permutations and combinations" where a permutation of $[n]$ could be shorter than $n$. What is meant her is simple a true permutation of $[n]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the numbers $1, 2, .., n$ into two sets $A, B$ - $A$ containing all odd numbers and $B$, the even ones. Suppose that $i$ and $f(i)$ are not both in $A$ or $B$ for $ i \in \{1, 2,... n \}$.

Suppose $n$ is odd. Then without loss of generality $|A| = |B| + 1$. Each member in $A$ must be mapped to a member in $|B|$. By the pigeonhole principle this is impossible so for at least one $j \in \{1, 2,... n \}$ , $j$ and $f(j)$ are both odd or both even.

$\implies 2 \ | \ (j - f(j))$ for some $j$.

$\implies 2 \ |  \ (1-f(1))*(2-f(2))*...*(n-f(n)) \implies $ the product is even.

> A permutation of length $n$ is a bijection from $\{1, 2,.., n \} \rightarrow \{1, 2,.., n \} $

Comment: I think you can say that in at least one case both $j$ and $f(j)$ are odd.

Answer (score 2):

There are $(n+1)/2$ odd numbers $i\in[n]$, and equally many numbers $i$ such that $f(i)$ is odd. Since that makes $n+1$ in all, the pigeonhole principle says that at least one $i$ is counted twice: both $i$ and $f(i)$ are odd. But then $i-f(i)$ is even, and so is the entire product.

Here is a proof without the pigeonhole principle, by contradiction. For the product to be odd, all $n$ factors $i-f(i)$ must be odd. But since $n$ is odd, that would make the *sum* of the factors odd as well. But that sum is $0$, isn't that odd? (Indeed it isn't.)

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (i - f(i)) = 0$$
Thus, the sum of an odd number of terms is $0$, so there exists at least one even term in this sum. Hence,
$$2 \mid \prod_{i=1}^n (i - f(i)).$$